# d3.js - use brush over a sequence of rectangles

Tags: d3.js, brush

I am learning the brush concept of d3 and want to know if it is possible to use brush on sequence of rectangles instead of x-axis. I have 12 rectangles created and would like to stretch over the rectangles using the mouse.

My code is :

```
    var margin = {top: 4, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("id","svgtimer")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("TimerData.json", function(data) {
       CreateLegend('#timer',svg,"rectangle",data,'Jan','Dec');
    })


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")




  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
    .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))
    .on("brush", brushed);

    svg.append("g").call(brush);


 function brushed() {
    console.log(brush.extent());
}




function CreateLegend(div,svg,svgid,data,header,trail)
{

      console.log(data);
      var traillength=0;
      var svgelem;
    //alert("Non-empty");

    //d3.json(filepath, function(data) {
    console.log(" the svg id is "  +svgid); 

    jsondata = data;

    rectangle= svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect");
      var RectangleAttrb = rectangle

                        .attr("id", function (d,i) { return svgid + "id" + i ; })
                        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("width",function(d) { return d.width; } )
                   .attr("height",function(d) { return d.height; })
                       .style("stroke", function (d) { return d.border;})
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });





            var textparam = svg.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text");

            var yearheader = d3.select("#header");

        if(yearheader.empty()) 
        {

            var textheader = svg.append("text").attr("dx",20).attr("dy",5).text(header).attr("id",header).attr("style","margin-bottom:21px;border-bottom: solid 2px #ffd97f; font-size:12px;")
        }

            if (trail.length == 0)
        {
              //console.log(textheader);
              d3.select(header).attr("style","font-size:15.1px;text-decoration:underline");
          //svg.attr("style","text-decoration:underline");
        }


        var text = textparam .attr("x", function (d) { traillength = d.x_axis + d.width +10; return d.x_axis + d.width +10; })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis + d.height-5; })
                       .attr("width",30 )
                       .attr("height",20)
                       .attr("style", "text-decoration:none")
                       .text(function(d) { return d.text; });


    var yearheader = d3.select("#trail");


    if (trail.length > 0 && yearheader.empty() )
      {

        svg.append("text").attr("id","trail").attr("dx",traillength-10).attr("dy",5).text(trail).attr("style","margin-bottom:21px;border-bottom: solid 2px #ffd97f; font-size:12px;" )
      }


    //});


}
```

My timerdata is :

[

```
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":60, "y_axis": 10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":80, "y_axis": 10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":100, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":120, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":140, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color": "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":160, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":180, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color": "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":200, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":220, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":240, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"},
   { "x_axis":260, "y_axis":10,"width":20,"height":15,"color" : "#ffffff","border":"#000000"}



]
```

How do i use the brush to stretch on the rectangles. I looked at some samples and found that brush is associated with x-axis. Is it not possible to use brush on these rectangles?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here -- it doesn't really matter what you're brushing over. A brush is usually associated with a scale (not an axis) because you usually need to translate user coordinates to screen coordinates, but you don't have to do that. In any case, using a brush as is should work just fine.

Comment: Lars, in this example i would try to brush the set of rectangles. how do i implement the scale for the rectangles here? so that i can brush over this. So when i move from rect 1 to rect2 i can do something.

Comment: You can use a dummy scale -- are you looking for [this](https://vida.io/documents/KvCvrrccbidFwgsQK)?

Comment: bingo!!!!.Exactly......also i need to get the id of the rect which got brushed.

Comment: You just need to check which rectangles overlap for that, see the updated document [here](https://vida.io/documents/KvCvrrccbidFwgsQK).

Comment: Lars. when i added the code to brush, the rectangles are not getting displayed. only the last 2 rectangles are getting displayed. i checked the inspector too, only 2 rect drawn.

Comment: Does it work for you in the document I've created? You should be able to copy the code from there.

Comment: yes. it works fine. i rectified the issue. It works fine now.

Comment: few clarifications: what does this .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width])) and    .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height])) do? Also how do i adjust the height and width of the brush do?. Also what does this statement do - return d.x_axis <= e[1][0] && d.x_axis + d.width >= e[0][0] && d.y_axis <= e[1][1] && d.y_axis + d.height >= e[0][1];
Apologize if i am being naive.

Comment: If that solves your problem I can write up an answer with explanations. Just want to make sure that it does first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `d3.svg.brush()` without any special modifications. I've taken your code and implemented it [here](https://vida.io/documents/KvCvrrccbidFwgsQK). The code that initialises and attaches the brush is as follows.

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
  .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))
  .on("brush", brushed);
svg.append("g").call(brush);
```

This initialises the brush and assigns identity scales to the `x` and `y` dimensions. In your code, you're not actually using scales to convert the user to screen coordinates, but taking the user coordinates directly. This is what the identity scales does. The domain of each is set to the respective dimension of the graph to tell the brush how big the brushed area can be.

You can specify an initial extent of the brush using the [`.extent()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent). The implementation of the handler looks like this in your case.

```
function brushed() {
  var e = brush.extent(),
    selected = svg.selectAll("rect").filter(function(d) {
    return d.x_axis <= e[1][0] && d.x_axis + d.width >= e[0][0] && d.y_axis <= e[1][1] && d.y_axis + d.height >= e[0][1];
  })
  console.log(selected);
}
```

It first gets the current extent of the brush and then filters the drawn rectangles by it. That is, for each rectangle, the code checks whether it overlaps with the brush rectangle. If it does, it is retained in the list `selected`. Note that this implementation is not particularly efficient as it iterates over all the rectangles. This is not a problem in your case as you only have a few, but if you want to use this with many more rectangles in two dimensions, I recommend using a more efficient data structure, such as a quadtree.